# A class in one namespace dynamically instantiating an object outside its namespace

Tags: apex, namespace, inheritance

I have a managed package with namespace `myNamepace` and a class `ClassA` which resides in that package will be dynamically instantiating objects of all subclasses of a particular abstract class `SuperClass`.

As of now, I assume the classes are in the same namespace and thus do:

```
// in ClassA
public SuperClass getInstance(String className) { 
    // classnName = 'ClassB' or 'ClassC', etc...
    return (SuperClass) Type.forName(className).newInstance();
}
```

However, if `ClassB` or `ClassC`, or any other subclass of `SuperClass` resided outside `myNamespace`, what would have to change? How would I then be able to figure out ClassB's namespace and then instantiate it? And what if `ClassB` does not have a namespace (for example, if it resides in a dev org), then can `ClassA` still instantiate it?

Comment: Edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) includes this comment about `Type.forName(namespace, name)`:

> Use this method instead of
>   forName(fullyQualifiedName) if it will be called from a managed
>   package installed in an organization with no defined namespace. To get
>   the name of a local type, set the namespace argument to an empty
>   string or null. For example, Type t = Type.forName('', 'ClassName');.

which covers the no-namespace case.

I've used code like this in a managed package to allow a class name to be set in a custom setting in the form "myNamepace.ClassA" or just "ClassA" for no namespace:

```
public static Type typeFor(String name) {
    Integer index = name.indexOf('.');
    if (index != -1) {
        // With namespace "ns.Type"
        return Type.forName(name.substring(index), name.substring(index + 1, name.length()));
    } else {
        // Just "Type"
        return Type.forName(null, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this. Thanks!

Comment: @Shiva It's an awkward API - I've shared your pain.

Comment: Oh, got another question. If `name` is a class belonging to the same managed package, which is the best function to use? `forName(null, class)` or `forName(class)`? If you use one where you're supposed to use the other, is it going to spit exceptions at you or quietly flop?

Comment: @Shiva Definitely not `forName(null, class)`; think the cleanest approach is to specify the namespace i.e. "yourpackagenamespace.YourClassName" rather than rely on that defaulting through one of the APIs.